# Restore from Azure Portal - Azure Backup Server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

[image]Hello,

I used Azure Backup server to Backup SQL DB in Azure Backup Vault. I have a question suppose i lost my Backup Server then is it possible to recover data from Azure Portal? I tried recovering from portal but it is giving me no option there.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have SQL Azure [automated backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups#point-in-time-restore) which give you up to 35 days of retention period depending on the tier of the database. Vault backups is more a long-term retention backup that you should use if the data loss occurred outside the current retention period for automated backups.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Alberto . My problem is about Recovery option from Portal i.e. how i can recover data from portal if i lost my Azure Backup Server?

Comment: Use this procedure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups#point-in-time-restore

Answer (score 0):

You can recover the data, by installing the MABS software on a different server and providing the same passphrase as the one that was used to register, there is no direct way to recover data from the Azure portal

Answer (score 0):

If your Backup Server crashed or destroyed then you cannot recover from the azure portal but still you can recover the data from the Recovery Service Vault by creating new backup server but you need the pass-phrase to decrypt the data. You may follow the below step.

1. Build new VM, install Azure Backup Server and registered the server to the same Recovery Service Vault.
2. Use the same pass-phrase while registering the server. The file which contains previous pass-phrase should look like Microsoft_Azure_Recovery_Services_Agent_6_19_2017_05_10_43.txt.
3. Create protection group and initiate recovery process.